# How can I all display all entries in a custom exception via the quickwatch window?

Tags: c#, debugging, exception

I created a custom exception that inherits from `Exception` and added a single extra property.

```
public class EntriesException : Exception
{
    public EntriesException()
    {
        Entries = new Entry[0];
    }

    public Entry[] Entries { get; set; }
}
```

When I throw this exception however, the `Entries` property simply displays the first entry of many in the `Quickwatch` window. I cannot drill down into the list to show the contents/properties of each separate object. This is quite useless as I'm designing this as an API.

The `Entry` objects are simple POCO's with nothing but getters and setters in them.

```
public class Entry
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Context { get; set; }

    public string File { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Entry '{Name}' with context '{Context}' in '{File}'";
    }
}
```

Overriding the `ToString()` method or changing the collection type didn't seem to make a difference.

Sreenshot for clarity (apologies for the blurring, they're strict on security here) https://i.stack.imgur.com/wy3OH.png

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: provide Minimal, Working example that can reproduce the issue; I've create an exception from the source you've provided, thrown an instance of it and in quick watch i can see 2 entries that I've added when I was throwing it.

Comment: @PawełŁukasik Not sure what else you need, this is literally the only relevant code. Hence why I don't get why it's not working.

Comment: @PawełŁukasik I just tried this in a new console application with only the POCO and the Exception - does not work. Can you send me your version so I can compare please?